# Able to recover a deleted branch using git tag

Tags: git

I have a test repository with a master and test branch.  I did make few changes in test branch and did a tagging of the test branch.  Then I deleted the test branch (no, I did not merge with master).  Surprisingly, when I tried to checkout using the tag which I did earlier, I was able get the test branch which I deleted earlier (of course in DETACHED HEAD state, in "no branch").  How this is possible? Can someone help me understand this??

Comment: What do you expect? When you tag a commit you will be able to get back to that commit via the tag, regardless if it's on any branch.

Comment: @knittl, I am from CVS background, I had expected that once I delete the branch, the tag which was present for a commit on the branch would also be deleted..

Comment: No, a tag is permanent and a perpendicular concept to a branch. Both can exist independently in Git.

Comment: Use [`git-reflog`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Data-Recovery) for this kind of task.

Answer (score 10):

Git objects are not immediately deleted after operations (for example, they can be recovered with `git reflog`). You have to explicitly use `git gc` (which calls `git prune` too) to manually delete them, or wait an amount of time controlled `gc.pruneexpire` to automatically prune them (if that's enabled by `gc.auto`).

Besides, objects are permanently deleted only when there's no reference to them, and in this case, you still have a Tag on it, so the commit and its history is preserved.

Check this command output:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

It will give you an overview of your repository, the commits you see here won't be permanently deleted by garbage collector.

Comment: it means that the tag which I had created is a reference, if that is the case, when I did a checkout using the tag, why did it checkout as DETACHED HEAD state??  As per my understanding, DETACHED HEAD state results when HEAD is not pointing to any reference (tag or branch) but it is pointing to a commit-hash (SHA1 of commit).  Can you help me understand it better??

Comment: It's a "detached head" because it doesn't belong to any branch, you deleted it.

Comment: "fatal: unrecognized argument: --online"  ??  git 1.8.x, Win7

Comment: Sorry, I meant `--oneline`, it makes the command only print one line per commit. Thanks.

Comment: Best reference to understand this: [Git References](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References)